Needing help with a design assignment
For a class I am taking we were assigned to create a circuit where we are given a signal with lots of noise, design a circuit that will cutoff any frequency higher than 1.87 kHz with a sharp roll-off. You may create alternate voltage sources to your power device. Signals are within 10-15 V. Use indicator lights to demonstrate board status. Reverse polarity protection on the input side. Minimize voltage drop and power draw from your device.
I know to have a cutoff frequency of 1.87 kHz we have to implement an active low-pass filter with a sharp roll-off such as a Sallen-Key topology with operational amplifiers. Other than that I don't know where to start. It is due on Tuesday and I don't know how to make a low-pass filter schematic. I don't know how I would implement these components in Multisim and what resistors, sources and capacitors I should use. We were very underprepared on this assignment. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

See this http://www.calculatoredge.com/electronics/sk%20low%20pass.htm or this one http://www.calculatoredge.com/electronics/sk%20high%20pass.htm

The facts I see: (1) indicator lights, but no information about what they indicate; (2) reverse polarity protection on the input, which suggests it's not AC but has a DC bias to it or is pulsed DC -- perhaps the 10-15V spec relates here but I'm not sure how; and (3) whatever the input is it has "lots of noise" but no further information on that score. We do have a cutoff frequency but no information on "sharp." What's meant by "voltage drop" which is odd term to use for a signal? Hopefully, your educational institution is providing you with more information than you've shared.

@periblepsis this is unfortunately all I have. It is meant to be open-ended so there is no one way to do it. The information I provided is all there is in the requirements section. I think the LED's are to indicate that the circuit is working. I am not sure how to add photos to comments but I have a screenshot of the assignment.

@Antonio51 Thank you!! Would you know if I should use a low-pass filter or a high one?

It is in your question ... <<< design a circuit that will cutoff any frequency higher than 1.87 kHz >>> ... so it is a "low pass"  Add an R=100 Ohm/C=1 nF filter at output to greater roll-off (adapt the values by simulation).

It doesn't have to be an active filter. That would be the best option as it means you can use much smaller components, but a passive filter could do the job too.

@Reyva I can't interpret your work for you. You go to the lectures. You have the hand-outs. The experiences that have accumulated over time. Etc. I have nothing. It isn't useful to throw mud at the wall to see what sticks. You need to make some decisions and interpretations. That's not our business to guess at. Once you make those decisions, help may follow. Also, Analog as a useful active filter designer tool. That may get much of what you want and you can try out different ideas with it, as well. But it won't design for signals with DC offset.

Made with microcap v12.
Here is (start point) what you get with an R-C after the filter.
You need to add some other hardware (LEDs, ... ).

